# js not working due to internal script asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a page on which a div appears to show a message with span tag "x".When user clicks the x the div hides. It works fine and the js code exists in external script file. Now i used some inline jscript in this page and the div thing wont work anymore. I also tried using this inline in external file but even just calling the file name on page makes the div unwork. Here is my page code. The 'msgpanel' is the div that appears and hides.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mCSSv2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WU_adddetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="mCSSv2.WU_adddetails" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

  </asp:Content>

  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script src="/js/popup.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/pasteimage.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #upload_image {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: #F5F6F7;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 15px;
      }
      
      #upload_image img {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        margin-top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      
      .btn:hover {
        background: #3cb0fd;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .modal {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 100;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
      }
      
      #divImage {
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: White;
        height: 550px;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 3px;
        border: solid 1px black;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Begin of #main-content -->
    <div id="main-content">
      <div class="container_12">
        <div id="msgpanel" runat="server">
          <asp:Literal ID="msg" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>

        </div>

        <%--<div class="grid_12">
                <h1>
                    Western Union Customer & Transaction Details</h1>
                <p>
                </p>
            </div>--%>

          <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="block-border">
              <div class="block-header">
                <h1>
                  Add Info</h1>
                <span></span>
              </div>
              <div class="_100">
                <p>

                </p>
              </div>


              <div id="divImage">
                <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                      <img id="imgLoader" alt="" src="images/loader.gif" />
                      <img id="imgFull" alt="" src="" style="display: none; height: 500px; width: 590px" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                      <input id="btnClose" type="button" value="close" onclick="HideDiv()" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>


              <div id="upload_image" style="float:center; margin-top:30px; margin-left:800px;  height:100px; width:150px; position:absolute;">

                <img id="imgDemo" runat="server" alt="nadira image" style="margin-top:50px" src="js/Paste.png" ondblclick="return LoadDiv(this.src);" />
                <input type="hidden" name="photo" />
                <p runat="server" id="uploadMsg" visible="false"></p>
                <%--<button type="submit"  class="btn">Submit</button>--%>
              </div>

              <div id="divBackground" class="modal"></div>



              <div class="block-border">

                <table>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      CNIC no.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cnic" runat="server" CssClass="uniform-button hover" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="13" Margin-left="-2.5px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);"
                      />
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="Searchbtn" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" onclick="Searchbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br />



                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="rv1_txt_cnic" ControlToValidate="txt_cnic" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" runat="server" />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rv2_" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_cnic" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br /> </td>


                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Nadira
                      Verisys Image<br />
                      <%--<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                                
                                    <asp:Button class="button" ID="btnUpload" onClick="btnUpload_Click" 
                                        runat="server" Text="Upload" Width="60px" CausesValidation="False"></asp:Button>--%>
                        <%--<asp:Button class="button" ID="save_btn" onClick="savebtn_Click" 
                                        runat="server" Text="Save" Width="60px" CausesValidation="False"></asp:Button>--%>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>
                <!--first div -->


                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="textfield" style="margin-top: -1px">
                                Sender Name </label><br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_sender" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="50" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />

                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_sender" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />

                    </td>
                    <td>

                      &nbsp;<label for="textfield">
                                Receiver Name</label><br /> &nbsp;
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_rcvr" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="50" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />

                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_rcvr" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <label for="textfield">
                                CNIC Expiry Date    (Format:mm-dd-yyyy)</label><br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_expirydt" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /> <br />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_expirydt" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Select Date" SetFocusOnError="True" InitialValue="" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_expirydt" ErrorMessage="Date was in incorrect format" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-\d{4}$">
                      </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="textfield">
                               CNIC Issue Date    (Format:mm-dd-yyyy)</label><br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_issuedt" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="13" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />

                      <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="17px" ImageUrl="~/img/calendar.png" onclick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="21px" CausesValidation="False" />--%>

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_issuedt" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Select Date" SetFocusOnError="True" InitialValue="" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_issuedt" ErrorMessage="Date was in incorrect format" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-\d{4}$">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                        <%--<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"   Visible="False" Width="375px" 
                                BackColor="White" CaptionAlign="Top" CellPadding="3" CssClass="center" 
                                onselectionchanged="Calendar2_SelectionChanged">
                                <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

                                    <TitleStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                                    </asp:Calendar></p>--%>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                  <tr>

                    <td>
                      <label for="textfield">
                                Date of Birth    (Format:mm-dd-yyyy)</label><br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_dob" runat="server" placeholder="" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="13" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />

                      <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="17px" ImageUrl="~/img/calendar.png" onclick="ImageButton3_Click" Width="21px" CausesValidation="False" />--%>

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_dob" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Select Date" SetFocusOnError="True" InitialValue="" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_dob" ErrorMessage="Date was in incorrect format" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-\d{4}$">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                        <%--<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar3" runat="server"   Visible="False" Width="375px" 
                                BackColor="White" CaptionAlign="Top" CellPadding="3" CssClass="center" 
                                onselectionchanged="Calendar3_SelectionChanged">
                                <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />

                                    <TitleStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                                    </asp:Calendar>--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label for="textfield">
                                Mobile No.</label><br />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_mob" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="11" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />
                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator4" ControlToValidate="txt_mob" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" runat="server"
                      />
                      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_mob" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>

              </div>
              <!--first div end -->

              <div class="block-border">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width:272px;">
                          <label for="textfield">
                               Bank Name </label>
                          <asp:DropDownList Font-Size="Small" ID="ddl_bank" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_bank_SelectedIndexChanged" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Text="Select Bank Name"></asp:ListItem>

                          </asp:DropDownList>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddl_bank" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select a bank" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:270px">
                          <label for="textfield">
                                Account Type </label>
                          <asp:RadioButtonList Font-Size="Small" ID="rad_acctype" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" AppendDataBoundItems="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IBAN" Text="IBAN"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="BBAN" Text="BBAN"></asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:RadioButtonList>

                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="rad_acctype" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Select Account Type" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          &nbsp;<label for="textfield">
                                WU Available Bal</label><br /> &nbsp;
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_wubal" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" Rows="1" Width="270px" ReadOnly="True" Font-Size="Small" Enabled="false" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" />
                        </td>

                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                      <tr><br />
                        <td style="width:272px">
                          <label for="textfield">
                                Account no.</label>
                          <asp:DropDownList Font-Size="Small" ID="ddl_accno" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_accno_SelectedIndexChanged" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Text="Select Account No"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList><br /> &nbsp;
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_accno" runat="server" CssClass="uniform-button hover" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="24" Width="240px" Font-Size="Small" />

                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddl_accno" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select an account" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="txt_accno" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter account number" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                                     ControlToValidate="txt_accno" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display="Dynamic"
                   EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" runat="server"/>
                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                                    ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txt_accno" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty"
                                    SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <label for="textfield">
                               Beneficiary Account Title</label>
                          <asp:Label ID="tft" runat="server" Text=" [Title Fetch Status]" style="font-style:italic"></asp:Label><br />
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_acctitle" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Enabled="False" Width="270px" ReadOnly="True" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="fetch" runat="server" Text="Click to Fetch Title" CausesValidation="False" onclick="fetch_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                          <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false">
                            Beneficiary Account Title not found </asp:label><br />

                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_acctitle" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                          &nbsp;<label for="textfield">
                                Amount to Transfer</label><br /> &nbsp;
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_amt" runat="server" style="text-align:right" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="06" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />
                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="txt_amt" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" runat="server"
                          />
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_amt" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Valid Transfer Amount" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <br />
                          <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" Operator="LessThan" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="txt_amt" ControlToCompare="txt_wubal" ErrorMessage="Insufficient amount in WU account" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <label for="textfield">
                                MTCN No.</label><br />
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_mtcn" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="10" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />

                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator3" ControlToValidate="txt_mtcn" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ErrorMessage="Please enter numbers only" runat="server"
                          />
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_mtcn" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Field cannot be empty" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>

                        <td>
                          <label for="textfield">
                                Purpose of Payment</label><br />
                          <asp:DropDownList Font-Size="Small" ID="ddl_pop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="270px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl_pop_SelectedIndexChanged" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True" Text="Select Purpose "></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Other"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Test "></asp:ListItem>
                          </asp:DropDownList><br /> &nbsp;
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_pop" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="50" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" />

                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="ddl_accno" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select an account" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" InitialValue="0" ControlToValidate="txt_accno" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter account number" SetFocusOnError="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                          &nbsp;<label for="textfield">
                                Relationship with Beneficiary</label><br /> &nbsp;
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_rel" runat="server" CssClass="uploader" CausesValidation="True" Rows="1" MaxLength="50" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                  </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </div>


              <table>
                <tr>

                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- first div closing-->
          <br />
          <div class="clear">


          </div>
          <div class="clear">


          </div>
          <div class="block-actions">
            <ul class="actions-left">
              <li>
                <asp:Button ID="btnClear" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="New Transaction" CausesValidation="False" onclick="btnClear_Click"></asp:Button>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <%--<ul class="actions-left">
                            <li><asp:Button ID="save" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="save" 
                                    CausesValidation="False"></asp:Button></li>
                        </ul>--%>
              <ul class="actions-right">
                <li>
                  <asp:Button ID="BtnExec" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="button" onclick="BtnExec_Click" OnClientClick="SetTarget();" CausesValidation="true" />
                </li>
              </ul>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                function SetTarget() {

                  document.forms[0].target = "_blank";

                }
              </script>



              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />

          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="clear">


    </div>





    <!--! end of #main-content -->
    <asp:HiddenField ID="IDs" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>



  </asp:Content>
```

Here is my script file that has hide code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  /*
   * Closable Alert Boxes
   */
  $('span.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
  });

(function($) {
  $.pasteimage(function(value) {
    $("#upload_image img").attr("src", value);
    //add hidden input to form
    var sourceSplit = value.split("base64,");
    var sourceString = sourceSplit[1];
    // Write base64-encoded string into input field
    $("input[name='photo']").val(sourceString);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? Can you reproduce the error on jsFiddle? That would help others a lot to find what's causing the error. You may also take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and clean up html code you posted and keep only the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the asp.net rendering is not happening the you want it. Do following two things:

1. Add class to the "msgpanel" div.

   div id="msgpanel" class="msDiv" runat="server"
2. inScript, Find the div by using this class and slide up

   $('span.hide').click(function() {

   ```
     $('msDiv').slideUp();
   ```

   });